# Why can I call a private method on another instance than itself

Tags: c#, oop

I wonder why the following is allowed in C#:

When I define a class `MyClass` with a *private* method. Lets calls its instance `A`. Now I create an instance of `MyClass` in one of its public methods. This instance is called `B`. So `B` is an instance in `A` both of the same type.

I can call this private method on `B` from `A`.
To me the method is private meaning only `B` can call it itself and no other class. Apparently, another class of the same type can also call it on `B`.

Why is this?
It has to do with the exact meaning of the private keyword?

Code example:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private static int _instanceCounter = 0;

    public MyClass()
    {
        _instanceCounter++;
        Console.WriteLine("Created instance of MyClass: " + _instanceCounter.ToString());
    }

    private void MyPrivateMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Call to MyPrivateMethod: " + _instanceCounter.ToString());
    }

    public MyClass PublicMethodCreatingB()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start call to PublicMethodCreatingB: " + _instanceCounter.ToString());
        MyClass B = new MyClass();
        B.MyPrivateMethod(); // => ** Why is this allowed? **
        return B;
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: `private` is scoped to the class, not instances.

Comment: As you say, no other class! B is of type MyClass and you have access to it's private members inside MyClass. That's very simple.

Comment: Thank you, it is clear now!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`B.MyPrivateMethod();` is allowed because the method is being called within a method in the `MyClass` class.
You would not be able to call `MyPrivateMethod()` outside of methods in the `MyClass` class, however because `PublicMethodCreatingB` is in the same class, all private methods and variables are accessible to it.

Comment: Thanks, it helpt me out!